# Matlab Drawing: signal freq analysis

Tags: matlab, graph, drawing, fft, frequency

I'm new to matlab and signal processing issues, but I'm in need to answer the following questions to complete a project that depends on them.

suppose I have a grid where x-axis implements time, where as y-axis implements the amplitude. Knowing that sampling rate = 256. Based on the input signal:

1) How would I know the average frequency of that signal (knowing that it might not be a uniform signal)?

2) How would I represent/draw the "fast Fourier transform (FFT)"?

3) How would I represent/draw a the signal at a specific frequency (i.e. 5Khz)? (an online tool would be a great solution.)

a Matlab solution or reference would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: read Matlab's documentation http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html

Answer (score 0):

The MATLAB function [periodogram](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/signal/ref/periodogram.html) does pretty much everything you need - it takes care of windowing, FFT details and even plotting.